# Shop 'Storefront' does not exist exception while accessing Sitecore commerce application

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-connect

While accessing my Sitecore Commerce application, I am getting the following error.

> { 
>   "@odata.context":"http://localhost:5000/Api/$metadata#Sitecore.Commerce.Core.CommandMessage","MessageDate":"2018-01-15T06:47:14.4591881Z","Code":"Error","Text":"Shop
>   'Storefront' does not exist.","CommerceTermKey":"InvalidShop" }
>
> The complete exception is : Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred.
>
> Exception Details: Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException:
>   { 
>   "@odata.context":"http://localhost:5000/Api/$metadata#Sitecore.Commerce.Core.CommandMessage","MessageDate":"2018-01-15T06:47:14.4591881Z","Code":"Error","Text":"Shop
>   'Storefront' does not exist.","CommerceTermKey":"InvalidShop" }

Please suggest what could be the solution?

Comment: can you check this settings ? http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreCommerce/DeploymentGuide/en-us/index.html#Concepts/c_M_ChangesToDefaultSettings.html

Comment: Make sure your Sitecore instance has the https binding setup, sometimes that is the cause for this error

Answer (score 2):

If the above solution from Richard doesn't help, check /site/wwwroot/wwwroot/data/Environments/PlugIn.Content.PolicySet-1.0.0.json.

Make sure that the hostname and Sitecore credentials in this config file is correct as Sitecore uses this details to make API calls for Sitecore items. If you have to make changes to this config file you would have to do commerce bootstrap to see that the changes in effect.

I have documented this here - https://pratikthakker.blogspot.com/2018/07/shop-does-not-existcommercetermkeyinval.html

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why this might be the case:

a) If you renamed your storefront item (in. /sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/), you need to also change the site name as outlined in [this answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/10523/1173).

b) If 'Storefront' no longer exists, it might still be configured as the default storefront in Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config (defaultShopName)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your storefront name is the configured correctly and is named consistently. There are a couple of different places where you need to check:

1. Storefront Item in Sitecore Commerce Control Panel
2. Default Shop Name in Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config

For more details on how to update the default storefront name, please checkout my blog post here:
https://sitecoredude.com/how-to-change-the-default-storefront-name-in-sitecore-experience-commerce-9/

If you have already done the above, **clear your browser cache** and test again.

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed Sitecore commerce 9.2 SXA storefront I was getting the same error. I noticed that Sitecore 9.2 require Redis installed and running if Redis were not running you would get this error on the postman, and In commerce, BixFx will not load any menu items( merchandise/order etc.). Make sure Redis keep running.